# Facebook deep linking on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, deep-linking

this is my first time creating a iOS application. I m required to share my iOS app url schemes to Facebook. allowing user to click on the link and open my application.

I have tried Facebook link to your native app tutorial and i seem to miss some step. Is there other tutorial on facebook deep linking or example. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Turnpike open source framework. It makes it easy to implement deeplinking in your iOS app.

http://urxtech.github.io/

If you have any questions, feel free to reach out.

- john @ urx

Answer (score -2):

just follow the steps on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios.
you will find https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content in that page
Read carefully.